# Googlesheet AppScript - Tying to send confirmation email once date and time is inputted

Tags: javascript

I am new to coding and still learning, I tried to write the code according to the youtube video and trying to implement it but its not working. We got given a scenario

We have a candidate that has a name, email, role. Once they are confirmed for the role they get email with date and time. However, email need to be automatically once we input the date and time.

They will get an email with date and time with message

[image]

```html
function AutoEmail() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("AutoEmail2");

  var rng = ss.getRange("A2:G").getValues();
  //var rng = ss.getRange("A2:F").getValues(),objectPretendingString = JSON.stringify(objectPretendingString) 
  var template = ss.getRange("I2").getValue();
  
  for(var i = 0;i < rng.length;i++){
    var FinalMessage = template
    .replace("NAME",rng[i][1])
    .replace("DATE",rng[i][5])
    .replace("TIME",rng[i][6])
    .replace("SUBJECT",rng[i][3])
    .replace("TIME",Utilities.formatDate(new Date([i][6]),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"h:mm"))
    .replace("DATE",Utilities.formatDate(new Date([i][5]),"GMT","DD-mm-yyyy"));

    GmailApp.sendEmail(rng[1][0],rng[6][0],rng[5][0])
  }

  console.log(FinalMessage);
  
}
```